# How to use discord.js .setSelfDeaf() in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

My join.js Code is Below :-
I want the bot to auto self deafen when ever it joins any Voice Channel.

```
module.exports = {
  name: "join",
  description: "Joins your voice channel",
  category: "music",
  execute(message, args) {  
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.member.voice.channel.join().then((connections) => {
        message.channel.send({
          embed: {
            color: message.client.messageEmbedData.color,
            author: {
              name: "✔️ Hey, i joined your voice channel",
            },
            timestamp: new Date(),
          },
        });
      });
    } else {
      message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          color: message.client.messageEmbedData.color,
          author: {
            name: "❗ You are not in a voice channel",
          },
          timestamp: new Date(),
        },
      });
    }
  },
};
```

I tried many way but can't implement .setSelfDeaf(true) .

Someone please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`VoiceState#setSelfDeaf`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) to achieve that. It's pretty easy to do so.

---

```js
if (message.guild.me.voice.channel) { // Checking if the bot is in a VoiceChannel.
    message.guild.me.voice.setSelfDeaf(true); // Using setSelfDeaf to self-deafen the bot.
};
```

---

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "join",
    description: "Joins your voice channel",
    category: "music",
    execute(message, args) {
        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
            message.member.voice.channel.join().then((connections) => {
                message.guild.me.voice.setSelfDeaf(true);
                message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        color: message.client.messageEmbedData.color,
                        author: {
                            name: "✔️ Hey, i joined your voice channel",
                        },
                        timestamp: new Date(),
                    },
                });
            });
        } else {
            message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    color: message.client.messageEmbedData.color,
                    author: {
                        name: "❗ You are not in a voice channel",
                    },
                    timestamp: new Date(),
                },
            });
        }
    },
};
```